# How to enable REST API in SQL Server Reporting Service 2017?

Tags: sql-server, rest, reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

I have been attempting to implement a solution to integrate SSRS reports into a react application, and have managed to use the report execution service 2005 to fetch a report in PDF format and return the file to the client app. The current implementation is all hard coded, and I need a way to allow users to select a report from a dynamically populated list. I thought the REST API documented here: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0 would be a good option to help achieve this, however the report server doesn't seem to have the REST API available at http://supercooldomain.com/reportserver/api/v2.0. Does anyone know how I can enable the rest API or point me to some resources? We are using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API should be enabled by default. To access it simply call it's URL:

`http://<reportservername>/Reports/api/v2.0/CatalogItems(Path='/testfolder')`